# reactive native mobile application print to printer brother qr810w

Tags: reactjs

I'm developing a mobile application with react native, I need to print a label directly to the printer, can anyone help me?

I found some example in java, but I need to know if anyone has been able to print straight to printer with reactive native.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, can you show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: https://github.com/BukhariMuslim/react-native-printer